# LWJGL project java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, lwjgl

I'm working on a project using LWJGL and I can't seem to get my jar to run. It runs fine inside my IDE (netbeans), but the jar itself gives me the error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.lwjgl.opengl.Display
```

I've tried a lot of things to fix this error. I think it has something to do with the LWJGL natives not being correctly linked.

I've linked the natives in netbeans by putting this in the VM options.

```
-Djava.library.path="C:\Users\Lemonzap\Desktop\Projects\Game Programming\LWJGL -3\native\windows\x64"
```

The path is the path to where my 64 bit windows LWJGL natives are kept.

I've also tried adding this line to the beggining of main.

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("lib/natives").getAbsolutePath());
```

I have a feeling that I need to change this line a bit though since there isn't a natives folder in my lib folder. I've spent a few days researching this issue and trying out other people's solutions with no luck. I would greatly appreciate some help with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your natives need to be *inside* your jar. I had a lot of issues with this when I tried to deploy my LWJGL project.

I used [Jarsplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice) to do it. It takes the IDE-built jar, adds the libraries and natives, and exports to a `.jar`, `.exe`, `.app`, or `.sh`.

Comment: I've tried jarsplice but get the same error. perhaps I did something wrong when using jarsplice.

Comment: Thanks that was it. I'm using lwjgl 3 and I noticed that there are about 5 times as many natives in 2.9.1 than in my 3 folder. I don't if there was an error when I downloaded 3 or something but trying jarsplice again but using the natives from 2.9.1 worked. The only problem now is that it cant seem to find any of my images or shader files.

Comment: The path I was using to my images was src/Src/Resources/Images and removing src fixed it. It works fine with both src's in netbeans but not in jarsplice. But it can't find my shaders even after removing src. The path for the shaders is src/Src/Resources/Shaders

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. I made a package where I put my shaders.

Answer (score 0):

On my Linux system, I had this error because the system library `libXxf86vm.so.1` was missing. This means that a missing external library is also able to produce this error. On your windows, you probably need an extra dll.

These command solved in for me (on Ubuntu trusty):

```
sudo apt-get install libxxf86vm1 fglrx
```

Btw: it's also possible that java/jni/lwjgl have problems with pathnames containing spaces...